# Include OpenID Connect claims to Firebase sign-in attributes

Tags: firebase, openid-connect, google-identity

We are using Google Identity platform as an Identity provider, and we currently have two providers:

- Email / Password
- SAML (SSO)

We use it only as authentication. Once the user is authenticated, we verify server-side the authenticity of the id token, and if verified, we will issue a JWT with our own key set. Some data needs to be appended to the token, such as custom client id that acts like a tenant ID so we know where to do requests.

We are interested in adding a new way to authenticate through OpenID Connect. The auth flow seems to work, however, in order to integrate in our current flow, we need to have at least the `given_name`, and the `family_name` fields that are sent by the client's identity provider. In this case, it will be Azure AD (new name Microsoft Entra)

As of now, the flow is as is:

```ts
// Scopes are already preconfigured with "openid profile email"
const provider = new OAuthProvider(ssoId);
await signInWithRedirect($auth, provider);
```

Once the user is authenticated, we have multiple options facing us:

- Getting Firebase's id token, and send it to our back-end. But we miss some informations: We don't have any information included in it. No email, first name, last name
- Extracting the Microsoft id tokenin which we can read `given_name` and `family_name`

```ts
const userCredential = await getRedirectResult($auth);
if (userCredential) {
  const credentials = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(userCredential);
  console.log(credentials); // Access Token + ID Token from Microsoft
  console.log(userCredential); // Decoded Firebase ID Token
}
```

Ideally, we would like to keep the current flow just like we do with SAML authentication, where those fields are mapped to fields we ask to the clients.

Unfortunately, in this situation with OpenID Connect, we only have this information in the token:

```json
{
  "name": "*redacted*",
  "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/*redacted*-dev",
  "aud": "*redacted*-dev",
  "auth_time": 1695129924,
  "user_id": "zLqx1u73QaU9uOmkaNvEZZbkNh42",
  "sub": "zLqx1u73QaU9uOmkaNvEZZbkNh42",
  "iat": 1695129924,
  "exp": 1695133524,
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {
      "oidc.*redacted*-azure-ad": [
        "VYmuzDUMQUlSkGnNLHVDQ-vxdvV9qJDhTEMJamqqzos"
      ]
    },
    "sign_in_provider": "oidc.*redacted*-azure-ad",
    "sign_in_attributes": {
      "ver": "2.0",
      "aio": "AWQAm/8UAAAApsgZB1l8/pUKK3DdCTzioVEHpJOT41hs7XiATk37ShUwjgYCa0HZIOJmOi2GgswENS+u6Sb3y7DVwqR2Na+6JBgiufC24Hn8VMJnP9o2u7fk8/xigzNRjs8S8Qydc4R9",
      "rh": "0.ATkAcY6U2Y_y7kWFt7vUytrJub9-rLRmV_5MvduzlkIsCrzgAJs.",
      "oid": "158e8a64-5d48-4641-bf76-7630a0aa79cd",
      "preferred_username": "*redacted*@*redacted*.onmicrosoft.com",
      "uti": "PsyrhHx2bk294jOC7FgPAA",
      "tid": "d9948e71-f28f-45ee-85b7-bbd4cadac9b9"
    },
    "tenant": "*redacted*-test-*redacted*-gnh1z"
  }
}
```

As you can see, we miss the required information.

**The question is: how to include some claims from the OpenID Connect id token in Firebase's `sign_in_attributes`** ?

If this is impossible, what would be the recommended flow to do so ?